# Share button not working in embedded Google Moderator

Tags: google-moderator

I am embedding a Google Moderator page in a page on my site (http://jeffadams.org/mydebateformat.html) but the "Share" button will not work.  Any thoughts on why?

The instructions I have followed can be found at -- http://support.google.com/moderator/answer/146014  Notice the note at the bottom of this page -- "Previously, we suggested embedding Google Moderator using IFRAMEs. This is the underlying device behind this new method, but the new method incorporates details that make authentication and sharing features work properly when in your embdedded pages."

Perhaps my problem is that my site doesn't have an SSL certificate?